# How can I access the log files on an android phone?

Tags: android, developer-tools

I am working on some experimental activity related to 5G connectivity.
I am having trouble getting a 5G phone to register to my experimental cell.
I see that during the startup process for the phone, that some log files are created.

I used the command `adb logcat` to dump a log from the phone to the device I have attached to the USB in developer mode.
However, the dump is not quite as informative as I would like.
By using the `adb shell ls -la` command, I can see the existence of some additional logs files, but they have permission restrictions.
One in particular at `./modem_log` is of specific interest.

Any idea how these files can be accessed without rooting the phone?

I was asked to add the output from the "adb shell ls -la" command

```
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root   1287 2018-08-08 00:01 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root   1287 2018-08-08 00:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root     27 2018-08-08 00:01 3rdmodem
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root     27 2018-08-08 00:01 3rdmodemnvm
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root     27 2018-08-08 00:01 3rdmodemnvmbkp
dr-xr-xr-x  67 root   root      0 2021-07-17 11:38 acct
drwxr-xr-x  16 root   root    320 2021-07-17 11:38 apex
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     11 2018-08-08 00:01 bin -> /system/bin
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     50 2018-08-08 00:01 bugreports -> /data/user_de/0/com.android.shell/files/bugreports
drwxrwx---   7 system cache  4096 2021-05-28 09:10 cache
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     19 2018-08-08 00:01 charger -> /system/bin/charger
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root      0 1970-01-01 08:00 config
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root    142 2018-08-08 00:01 cust
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     17 2018-08-08 00:01 d -> /sys/kernel/debug
drwxrwx--x  64 system system 4096 2021-07-17 11:38 data
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root     27 2018-08-08 00:01 debug_ramdisk
lrw-------   1 root   root     23 2018-08-08 00:01 default.prop -> system/etc/prop.default
drwxr-xr-x  24 root   root   5460 2021-07-17 11:38 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root     27 2018-08-08 00:01 eng
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     11 2018-08-08 00:01 etc -> /system/etc
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root    279 2018-08-08 00:01 hw_product
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root      8 2018-08-08 00:01 log -> /splash2
drwxr-xr-x  15 root   system  320 2021-07-17 11:38 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root    168 2009-01-01 00:00 odm
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root     27 2018-08-08 00:01 oem
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root   4096 2018-08-08 00:01 patch_hw
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root    109 2018-08-08 00:01 preas
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root     74 2018-08-08 00:01 preavs
drwxr-xr-x   6 root   root   4096 2018-08-08 00:01 preload
dr-xr-xr-x 660 root   root      0 1970-01-01 08:00 proc
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     15 2018-08-08 00:01 product -> /system/product
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     24 2018-08-08 00:01 product_services -> /system/product_services
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root     74 2018-08-08 00:01 res
drwxr-x---   1 root   shell   136 2018-08-08 00:01 sbin
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     21 2018-08-08 00:01 sdcard -> /storage/self/primary
drwxrwxr-x  20 root   system 4096 2021-07-08 07:23 splash2
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root    100 2021-07-17 11:38 storage
dr-xr-xr-x  15 root   root      0 2021-07-17 11:38 sys
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root    371 2018-08-08 00:01 system
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   shell   231 2018-08-08 00:01 vendor
drwxr-xr-x   7 root   root   4096 2018-08-08 00:01 version
ls: ./fstab.zram1024m: Permission denied
ls: ./fstab.zram1280m: Permission denied
ls: ./fstab.zram1536m: Permission denied
ls: ./fstab.zram2240m: Permission denied
ls: ./fstab.zram256m: Permission denied
ls: ./fstab.zram4096m: Permission denied
ls: ./fstab.zram512m: Permission denied
ls: ./fstab.zram768m: Permission denied
ls: ./init: Permission denied
ls: ./init.environ.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.mygote64.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.usb.configfs.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.usb.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.zygote32.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.zygote64_32.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./metadata: Permission denied
ls: ./modem_log: Permission denied
ls: ./resetFactory.cfg: Permission denied
ls: ./sec_storage: Permission denied
ls: ./ueventd.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./verity_key: Permission denied
```

Comment: Persistent log files are quite unusual on Android this seem to be a manufacturer specific modification of your device. On an unrooted phone the permissions you get via abd is the highest you can reach. If this is not enough then a rooted device is necessary. But you should edit your question and include the full line `ls -la` outputs so that we can see what permissions are required to access the `modem_log` file. You should also mention the directory this log is located in.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your comment.
The log files appear to be in the root directory, although I perceive that some may have been pushed to the sdcard.
Some example output:
---------
total 144
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root   1287 2018-08-08 00:01 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root   1287 2018-08-08 00:01 ..
drwxrwx--x  64 system system 4096 2021-07-17 11:38 data
drwxr-xr-x   1 root   root     27 2018-08-08 00:01 debug_ramdisk
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root      8 2018-08-08 00:01 log -> /splash2
ls: ./modem_log: Permission denied
-----------